# contentWindow.document.body is null

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a problem in my javascript which is just to resize an iFrame based on the content. I have it working in other places but for this one example it is throwing an error. Using the following code the `body` is null and therefore can't get `scrollHeight`.

```
if(document.getElementById('iFrameHelpDesk') != null)
{
    var Height = document.getElementById('iFrameHelpDesk').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

    document.getElementById('iFrameHelpDesk').height = Height + 40;
}
```

The html used is:

```
<iframe src="http://<snipped webaddress>" id="iFrameHelpDesk" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

Why does this not populate the `body` object?

Comment: If the iframe has a different domain to the main page, then you can't access it for security reasons.

Comment: @grc - The page is on the same domain so does not have this problem.

Comment: In addition to my point above, the above code also works for all other iframes that I specify. It's just this one that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly simply I took the code from the document load (`$(function() {})`) method and put it into it's own method for when the actual iframe loads. Ie.

```
$('#iFrameHelpDesk').load(function() {

    var Height = document.getElementById('iFrameHelpDesk').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

    document.getElementById(iFrameHelpDesk').height = Height + 40;

});
```

This works perfectly, as it should. But it's now confused me as to why some other iframes, which I perform similar code on, are working fine from within the document load. But this works and I'm happy enough with that.